# React native show updated data in other class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner in react native. Basically I have a drawer component in which I am loading a form and when I submit the form the fetch response data should be displayed in Home Screen.

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <HomeScreen {...props} screen='drawer' />} style={{ zIndex:4,width:width/2 }}>
        {/*<Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Signup" component={SignupScreen}/>*/}
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home"  component={HomeStackScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

In Home screen I have view for home page and a form for drawer which I am displaying based on property screen as you can see in the code.So I am in that same Home screen now and I open left drawer with the form and when I submit I want to display a additional component in same home screen. I am trying to use state but the data of Homescreen does not update since in return I am displaying content based on prop screen

```
{this.props.screen == 'drawer'  ?   
      <SafeAreaView style={{width:'100%',flex:1}}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
         </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView> : 
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TopBar navigation={navigation} />
        <PortSlider navigation={navigation} />
        {(this.state.status == false)?  <Results childName="Default data" />    : <Results childName="Updated data" /> }
    </View>
    }
```

I want to updated Results component in Home Screen. Please help me guys